# Naive Kafka Producer not working when I try to produce messages that are read from a file

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to write a naive Kafka Producer using Java. The application accepts two inputs:

1. Kafka topic name to which messages are to be produced
2. Path of file containing messages to be produced to Kafka

I wrote the following code. When I run it, I see that the `System.out.println` statements print the expected values but messages are not produced to Kafka for some reason. What should I change to make it work?

```
package com.myname.kafka.producer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class NaiveKafkaProducer {

    private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

    private static Producer<String, String> producer;

    private static String topic;

    private static BufferedReader br;

    static {
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("request.required.acks", "all");
        System.out.println("Creating Kafka producer with the following properties :: " + properties);
        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            if(args.length != 0) {
                topic = args[0];
                File file = new File(args[1]);
                br = new BufferedReader((Reader) new FileReader(file));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Check input arguments. Error thrown while populating arguments to local variables");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String msg;
        while ((msg = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Message to publish : " + msg);
            System.out.println("Topic : " + topic);
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, "", msg));
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Surprisingly the following code works (in which I have hard-coded everything):

```
package com.myname.kafka.producer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class NaiveKafkaProducer {

    private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

    private static Producer<String, String> producer;

    private static String topic;

    private static BufferedReader br;

    static {
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("request.required.acks", "all");
        System.out.println("Creating Kafka producer with the following properties :: " + properties);
        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            try {
                String[] msgs = new String[2];
                msgs[0] = "message 1";
                msgs[1] = "message 2";
                topic = "mytopic"
                for(String msg:msgs){
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, "", msg));
                }
                producer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught in main method while trying to produce the messages to Kafka");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a critial method invoked in the second snippet and missing in the first

`producer.close();`

from documenttion for that method:

> Close this producer. This method blocks until all previously sent requests complete.

When you invoke method `produce`, it doesn't mean in reality that the message was produced. Method returns you `future`. You can wait for each message to be produced by invoking `get()` on each result of produce method.